# Issues with Xcode & Realm browser

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, realm

So i've been trying to use Realm browser with Xcode so that it's easier for me to see and test my objects. But i seem to be running into a couple of problems with this.

The first issue is that with Realm Browser i'm not able to actually open up my files location using the dropdown option 'open common locations' so i can open it via the iPhone simulator. Even when i do open the file using alternative methods i keep on getting the following error in the console.

```
UserInfo = {
    Error Code=8,
    NSLocalizedDescription=Realm file is currently open in another process which cannot share access with this process. All processes sharing a single file must be the same architecture. For sharing files between the Realm Browser and an iOS simulator, this means that you must use a 64-bit simulator.
}
```

Which is weird because my Macbook is 64 bit since it's the Mid 2013 Macbook Air could anyone help solve this problem at all? Since it would make development so much easier if i could just use the browser application.

Comment: What versions of Realm and Realm browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

So i figured this out and realised that you have to be running the app using an iPhone 5s or higher

Comment: Eventhough I run with iPhone 6s,iPhone 7, I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Realm cannot be opened at the same time between processes of different architectures. iPhone 5 or earlier simulator is running as 32-bit process.